# Removing the leftmost column from a table in a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I don't know if it's possible but I would like to have this column removed. I'm not sure what the name of the column is, it lets you select an entire row. It doesn't have any purpose in my program.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `RowHeadersVisible` property to `false`.